# P-Channel FET Failing in Battery Protection Circuit

Tags: mosfet, batteries, battery-charging

I'm working on a battery pack monitoring/protection circuit! I've got a bidirectional switch, but I'm having some issues with FET_SW2 and I'm not entirely sure why. Seems to be failing short, with a relatively low RGS around 500 Ohms. It doesn't immediately fail, seems to only be happening after the battery pack has been used a few times.

Current theory is some kind of short circuit/over current failure. There is an overcurrent protection circuit, that is tested to be working. But I'm wondering if repeated short circuit might be degrading/damaging the FET significantly over time. There's no visible forms of failure in terms of burning/scorching.

Here's the link to the FET datasheet: aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AOD4189.pdf

Wondering if any of you guys might have any additional insight or ideas why the FET is failing. Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Vext is the voltage at the barrel jacks.
Ibat is measured across the lowside shunt via an instrumentation amp.
Vgate is gate voltage of the switching fets (fet_gates net).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't really get what's going on in a lot of that circuit, but if the PMOS is the current limiting element (different than outright opening when the current gets too high), it works hardest and heats up the most when its current limiting. SW1 is probably surviving because it can't do current limiting from left to right due to the body diode.

Comment: Well, you haven't shown what drives that MOSFET and neither have you linked the data sheet.

Comment: A lot of circuitry there. In addition to what DKNguyen said, another common cause of FET failure is when you turn it off, any stray inductance can cause a brief high-voltage spike. Usually there is a way to place a Schottky diode to clamp that voltage and prevent any damage.

Comment: I've added datasheet link to the original post. The driving circuitry is the switch enable part underneath FET_SW1. switch_en net is attached to a 5V MCU GPIO.

I think? the MOV (D3) should help with inductive kickback, but will look into it further to see if an additional diode would help.

Thanks again for the insight!

Comment: nice circuit. do you have any scope traces of the switching action?

Comment: no idea if this is an issue, but that 15V active overvoltage cut-off looks like it will take several tens of ns (?) to bring down the gate cap installed on the first fet. Vgs max is 20V, so if there's an internally generated spike in excess of 10V ...

Comment: Adding some scope captures of switching from short circuit fault! Let me know if you see anything! Seems to be an issue with the FET, posted on AVRfreaks as well, and someone mentioned having similar issues with the same FET. It was one of the lower cost options and seems to not handle stress too well :(

Comment: great, but that's hard to read without full resolution screen view. Is that 1ns or 1ms time div? Try to catch the highest point in the voltage between the mosfets, AND the point with the peak current. Both with 1us time div on the scope... // also look at AOD4189 datasheet Figure 9 (safe operating area) !!!

Comment: Maybe Vsource is overshooting when you turn off the FET's during short circuit. Can you add a TVS to Vsource to supress over-voltage? Also maybe try capturing it on the scope? Maybe a reverse biased diode on the output, also, to prevent FET_SW2's drain from getting pulled far below ground.